# TCPDF mysql result in pdf: getting only last result

Tags: php, mysql, tcpdf

I have a mysql query with result the following:

```
$retval = 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Attestation] => urkVIII,194b ) [1] => Array ( [Attestation] => urkVIII,195e ) [2] => Array ( [Attestation] => urkVIII,208a ) [3] => Array ( [Attestation] => urkVIII,213 )  )
```

I want to put each value corresponding to the key 'Attestation' into a pdf using `TCPDF`. I'm new to this `TCPDF` and can seem to get it even using the examples.
I tried this but i'm getting only the last result `(urkVIII,213)`

```
foreach ($retval as $row)
{
  foreach ($row as $result)
  {  
     $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
     $pdf->AddPage();
     $pdf->writeHTML($result, true, false, true, false, '');
  } 
}
$pdf->Output('somefile.pdf', 'I');
```

I think I have to use a while loop but I tried without succes. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
if($retval->num_rows()>0){
 foreach ($retval->result() as $row){
  $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
  $pdf->AddPage();
  $pdf->writeHTML($row, true, false, true, false, '');
  } 
}
```

Comment: When I do this I get a blanco page